# Can I use the same name query parameters with parent state and child state in UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-router

I want to implement a pagination function using AngularJS. Then I'm trying to achieve it by using **same state transition** and adding '**same name**' query parameter.

```
app.config ["$locationProvider", "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
  $locationProvider.html5Mode true

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'
  $stateProvider
    .state 'shops',
      url: "/shops?page"
      controller: "shopsController"
      templateUrl: "shops.html"
    .state 'shops.shop_detail',
      url : "/:shop_id"
      controller: "shopDetailController"
      templateUrl: "shop_detail.html"
    .state 'shops.shop_detail.menus',
      url: "/menus?page"
      controller: "menusController"
      templateUrl: "menus.html"
]
```

For example, if you want to see Page 2 of list of shops, URL inputed in browser is like the following.

```
/shops?page=2
```

And if you want to see Page 2 of list of menus in an specific shop, URL inputed in browser is like the following.

```
/shops/:shop_id/menus?page=2
```

But when I run this code, the following error occurred.

```
Error: error:modulerr 
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: Duplicate parameter name 'page' in pattern '/shops/:shop_id/menus?page?page'
```

I think this kind of implementation of pagination using query parameter is popular. But I cannot do this using UI-Router.
Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Oh, I've thought using 'page' query parameters anywhere in the website is normal. 
I'll try to change the way of implementing pagination into the following.
`/shops/page-2`
`/shops/:shop_id/menus/page-2`

Comment: Would like to point out, that it is simply not good practice, to use same names of the parameters. Would strongly suggest: do not do it. put your energy to different approach design... just my view...

Comment: I will absolutely follow your suggestion, @RadimKöhler. Appreciate it, Friend!